# CUDA Texture memory program not working

Tags: cuda

I'm learning to use textures in CUDA through simple examples. I tried the following example but it is not working. It is showing value 0.

```
#include "cuPrintf.cu"
texture<int,1,cudaReadModeElementType> ref;
__global__ void kernel(int *a)  
{  
    int b=tex1D(ref,0);  
    cuPrintf("value is %d",b);  

}  

int main()  
{  
    int *a;  
    cudaMalloc((void**)&a,32000*sizeof(int));  
    cudaMemset(a,1,32000*sizeof(int));  
    cudaChannelFormatDesc bit = cudaCreateChannelDesc<int>();  
    cudaBindTexture(0,ref,a,bit,32000*sizeof(int)); 
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(a);  
}
```

Comment: This code isn't complete and contains no API error checking at all. Please try a little harder when posting questions.

Answer (score 3):

You have allocated memory by using the `cudaMalloc` function. If you bind texture to the memory allocated with `cudaMalloc`, it is accessed using the function `tex1Dfetch()` inside the kernel. Using `tex1D` will return zeros.

But if you bind texture to the memory allocated by `cudaMallocPitch` or to `cudaArray`, then it is accessed using `tex1D` or `tex2D` functions inside the kernel.